# First Select If exists then delete under one Query

Tags: mysql

I have a Table by name Persons

My requirement is that , i need to check if there exists any records inside Persons  table with  PersonID = 1 and so if exists
delete it

I have tried as

```
DELETE FROM Persons
WHERE PersonID = 1
  AND EXISTS(SELECT PersonID FROM Persons WHERE PersonID = 1 LIMIT 1)
```

I am getting the following error

## 1093 - You can't specify target table 'story_category' for update in FROM clause

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ab2b51

could you please tell me how to fix this

Comment: Just do the query `DELETE FROM Persons WHERE PersonID = 1` - if the record doesn't exist nothing will happen.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for such trouble, just do "DELETE FROM Persons WHERE PersonID = 1"